Security: Form vs. AJAX request in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC
I'm reviewing the subscribe page of an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC project.
In terms of security, are these two approaches compatible to each other?
I do prefer AJAX since it allows me to have JS toaster for UX/feedback (invalid email etc.).
Option 1: in the view, use @model at top and a form element referencing that model.
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="AddNewUser" method="post" id="form-login">
    //Several div with the required properties
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</form>

Option 2: in the view, create an AntiForgeryToken, in JS create an AJAX request to send those information to the same endpoint.
let token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

$.ajax({
    url: '/Account/AddNewUser/',
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    data: {
        __RequestVerificationToken: token,
        //Required properties
    },
    success: function (response) { ... }
    error: function () { ... }
    complete: function () { ... }
});



are these two approaches compatible to each other?

Yes
The FormTagHelper injects antiforgery tokens into HTML form elements. The following markup in a Razor file automatically generates antiforgery tokens:
<form method="post">
    <!-- ... -->
</form>

ASP.NET Core adds a hidden form field similar to the following example:
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8NrAkS ... s2-m9Yw">

Then get the AntiForgeryToken with name="__RequestVerificationToken" and in JS create an AJAX request to send those information .
You can read Antiforgery in ASP.NET Core to know more.
